# How do you save an Instagram picture to the Android gallery?

Tags: gallery, instagram

How do you save Instagram picture to Android gallery?

Answer (score 3):

Instagram does not provide any options to download images or videos to the phone. However, you can use third party applications like "Instasave for Instagram" for doing this.

App Link:  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dstudio.tool.instasave&hl=en

1. Go to Play Store and Install Instasave application
2. Open Instasave app
3. Press home button and open Instagram App
4. Find image that you want to download
5. Click on Menu button (three dots)
6. Copy Share URL
7. Open Instasave app and you will see your image/video
8. Click on Download icon.

Answer (score 0):

*IF* you have a rooted device + xposed framework then check out the [instaprefs](https://www.xda-developers.com/instaprefs-xposed-module-instagram-features/) xposed module which adds extra functionality including saving assets:

- https://www.xda-developers.com/instaprefs-xposed-module-instagram-features/

> ❗️❗️❗️ ***WARNING**: If your device does not have root/magisk/xposed-framework already installed then be aware that trying to install them on incompatible hardware/software versions might BRICK your device and will most likely void your warranty! I would recommend **NOT** using your daily driver device for experimentation.*